# jQuery .offset() is behaving rather poorly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I have this `<div class="help">` (a help box or what you would call it) inside a `<td>` element. The help box is initially not displayed, but pops up when hovering over the `<td>`. The positioning of the help box is done via jQuery, by this small snippet:

```
var $help = $that.add($cousin).find("div.help").first();
var height = $help.parent().siblings().first().height();
$help.offset({
    top: $help.parent().offset().top + height,
    left: $help.parent().offset().left
});
$help.css("display", "block");
```

I find out if we have a help box, when hovering a `<td>` cell, get the height of the first of the first sibling of the `<td>` and then reposition. And this actually works!

...the first time. When hovering the `<td>` again the help box seems to be positioned outside the screen, as I see a horizontal scrollbar, whose width increases for each time I hover. So I guess there's something wrong with my use of `.offset()`. The help `<div>` has `position: absolute`, but I don't think this is CSS related.

Help a tall, handsome Swede out?

Comment: You will need to add `position: relative;` to the cell that contains `div.help` to make it work properly. But this may have undesired side effects...

Comment: are you sure that your variation $help define is true?

Comment: @Gavin Yes, I know, but it's still the same.

Comment: If you remove any code to set the offset etc, and try it like that, the div should stick to the top left of the cell it is in. Then you can simply use margin's to position.

Comment: @barlasapaydin My HTML guarantees that $help should contain a help box, but I should probably have some check there in the future.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/gRoberts/h3T6u/ for an example of what I am thinking of.

Comment: @Gavin Okay! Is that a valid solution for situations such as this? Should I leave `position: absolute` and `z-index: 10` in the CSS?

Comment: @Gavin Thank you! I will try that out, I'm going crazy over this positioning.

Comment: Assuming your trying to do what I have recreated in the fiddle code, then yes. Just need to make sure that `position: relative` works as expected on each of the browsers you are supporting. `z-index` shouldn't be an issue, but if you find you do have problems, it will help ;)

Comment: @Gavin Well, it works in Chrome, Firefox and Opera. Just some tinkering, but I know the cause. Sadly, the margin fix does not seem to be supported in IE 7–9 (what a surprise), and as our customers require that functionality... Hm. You don't have any idea? I'll think I'll move the margin stuff to the CSS file, but the jQuery `display: block` is necessary because two `<td>`:s will show the same help box.

Comment: I've just tested my fiddle in IE7+ and it works fine. Could you post a link to the page, or if possible, create a fiddle recreating your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments:

See my fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/gRoberts/h3T6u/ that shows how you can use css and the position property to achieve what your looking to do.

Hope that helps ;)

Comment: Yes, I see that it works in IE now. The problem is that IE is not reacting to my jQuery script and therefor only shows the help box when hovering the `<td>` that contains the help box. IE 7 seems to show the help boxes behind the `<td>` elements though, even if I up the `z-index`. You will definitely get the correct answer, but this business with IE always kills me.

Comment: if you apply `z-index` of say 2 to the TD (using css) and then apply an `z-index` of 3 to the .help (via css) which should help?

Comment: Doesn't seem to make any difference, but it is IE 7 specific. My priority now is that IE 7–9 won't load any of my jQuery. I noticed that just now, but I know it has worked earlier on. All other browsers are doing perfectly, both with the jQuery and the CSS.

Comment: Do you have a live site I can take a look at?

Comment: I fixed the loading of the JavaScript now, it was due to some stupid IE block I didn't notice. I don't have a live site now, but the only problem is the partly hidden help boxes in IE 7. I will play around with `z-index` a bit more, but feel free to give any input if you want.

Comment: Do you have overflow: hidden set on the table cells?

Comment: I did not, but I tried that as well now. No progress. I can probably get up a live site when I get home.

Comment: Here is my test version if you want to take a look: http://viktor.hembrink.se/4it/resus/grid2/ :)

Comment: I asked a new question about this problem. [Here it is.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644084/pop-up-help-box-hidden-behind-table-cells-in-internet-explorer-7)

Comment: Seems you cracked it ;) Glad you got it sorted.

Comment: Yup, thank you for your help! Now my only problem is that IE 8 is too stupid to interpret my jQuery.

Comment: If I get some time, I will try and look into it for you ;)

Comment: Okay, cool! I'm trying to fix up the code (I asked for some pointers [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14022/new-at-jquery-lack-of-structure) as I'm very new to jQuery) right now.