# Pop-up help box hidden behind table cells in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: jquery, html, css

Okay, so if you look at [this site](http://viktor.hembrink.se/4it/resus/grid2/) in Internet Explorer 7 (I use the browser mode tool in IE 9; just press F12). When hovering over the table cells in the first row the help box `<div class="help">` becomes hidden behind the second (okay: third) row's `background` property.

Why is this? It works in Chrome, Firefox, Opera and IE 8–9 (although the jQuery script is messed up in IE 8 for some reason). I have tried lower `z-index` on `<table>`, `<tr>` and `<td>`, but with no success yet.

**Edit #1.** Oh yeah, all borders in the table are not showing in IE 7. That is strange, no?

**Edit #2.** CodeJack's jQuery solution seems to be working.

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == "7.0") {
    var z = 1000;

    $("table, tr, th, td, div").each(function() {
        $(this).css("z-index", z);
        z -= 10;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Z-Index doesnt work properly in IE7. But there are ways.

A solution can be to place (absolutely) an iframe with opactiy set to 0 (CSS:filter:alpha(opacity=0)) directly behind the div.  The iframe must have the same width and height and be place at the same location (but behind) the div.

for Jquery there is solution here

http://www.vancelucas.com/blog/fixing-ie7-z-index-issues-with-jquery/

**Edit:** Regarding borders use `margin-collapse` rather `border collapse`

Comment: What do you know! This actually worked from what I can see. The `<iframe>` solution seemed to be messy, so I used the jQuery one. I'll update the question with the code.

Comment: By the way, you don't know why the borders in IE 7 aren't showing (see any other browser for comparison)? My jQuery script is also not working properly in IE 8, oddly enough, as it works in IE 7.

Comment: that JQuery is only for IE7...add and condition...and regarding table borders, show me the CSS code...

Comment: I know it is only for IE 7, that is why I checked browser and version in JavaScript. The CSS can be found on the demo page linked in the first question.

Comment: i know...i found that..i added the answer as well 2 hrs before ur comment...let me know how it works...

Comment: I tried switching `border-collapse` to `margin-collapse` in the `table.grid` rules, but nothing happened. Is `margin-collapse` in the standard or do I have to use `-<render engine>-margin-collapse`?